# Azure API Management devops resource kit - creator tool

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I'm using the Azure API Management DevOps resource kit to generate arm templates to use in a DevOps pipeline to configure my API management instances

https://github.com/Azure/azure-api-management-devops-resource-kit

This works well for APIs with a swagger definition but I have one WSDL that I also want to automate using the same process.  There doesn't appear to be great documentation around on how to do this with a WSDL file as opposed to a swagger file

I know as part of the config.yml file that the creator uses you can specify type: soap but it still requires you to point to an open API spec file

[image]

Can this process be carried out with a WSDL file?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to host the WSDL somewhere and reference it from there. Otherwise it can be easily imported.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-soap-api

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/connect-to-azure-api-management

However, if you are importing an API, you might come across some restrictions or identify issues that need to be rectified before you can successfully perform the import.

For WSDL below are the points we need :

- WSDL files are used to create SOAP pass-through and SOAP-to-REST
  APIs.
- SOAP bindings -Only SOAP bindings of style ”document” and “literal”
  encoding are supported. There is no support for “rpc” style or
  SOAP-Encoding. WSDL:Import - This attribute isn't supported.
  Customers should merge the imports into one document.
- Messages with multiple parts - These types of messages aren't
  supported. WCF wsHttpBinding - SOAP services created with Windows
  Communication Foundation should use basicHttpBinding - wsHttpBinding
  isn't supported.
- MTOM - Services using MTOM may work. Official support isn't offered
  at this time. Recursion - Types that are defined recursively (for
  example, refer to an array of themselves) are not supported by APIM.
- Multiple Namespaces - Multiple namespaces can be used in a schema,
  but only the target namespace can be used to define message parts.
  Namespaces other than the target, which are used to define other
  input or output elements, are not preserved. Although such a WSDL
  document can be imported, on export all message parts will have the
  target namespace of the WSDL.

For more info, follow this :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-api-import-restrictions